# How to change the output when printing a class object in order to avoid getting its address

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 classes: Student and ClassRoom.
I want the student class to get a student name and a list of the student's grades. I also added a method that calculates the average of the list and one that gets the students name and one that returns a tuple of the name and average.
I want the ClassRoom class to get a list of student objects and define a method that returns a list of the tuples when printing the ClassRoom object and not the objects' address.

Example:

```
Moses = Student("Moses", [97.5, 87, 60])
Dan = Student("Dan", [85, 96, 100])
students = ["Moses", "Dan"]
classRoom = ClassRoom(students)
print(classRoom)
# The output should be:
[("Moses", 81.5), ("Dan", 93.66666666666667)]
```

I know there's an option using a method of: `def __str__(self)`, but I have no idea how to use it properly.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
class Student():

    def __init__(self, student_name, grads_list):
        self.__name = student_name
        self.__grads = grads_list

    def get_grade_avg(self):
        return sum(self.__grads) / len(self.__grads)

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_name_and_average(self):
        return self.__name, self.__grads
```

```
class ClassRoom:
    def __init__(self, student_list):
        self.__students = student_list

    def __str__(self):
        for a_student in self.__students:
            return "[" + str(a_student.get_name_and_average) + "]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First, when you create a instance of ClassRoom object you need a list of student objects, not a list of string:

```
students = [Moses, Dan]
classRoom = ClassRoom(students)
```

You also need to create a **str** method for the student class:

```
class Student():

    def __init__(self, student_name, grads_list):
        self.__name = student_name
        self.__grads = grads_list

    def get_grade_avg(self):
        return sum(self.__grads) / len(self.__grads)

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_name_and_average(self):
        return self.__name, self.__grads

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}, {}".format(self.__name, self.get_grade_avg())
```

and in the end fix the **str** for the ClassRoom class:

```
class ClassRoom:
    def __init__(self, student_list):
        self.__students = student_list

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}]".format(", ".join(map(lambda x: "(" + str(x) + ")", self.__students)))
```

Comment: How can keep the names of the students as strings? I get e.g  [(Moses, 81.5), (Dan, 93.66666666666667)] instead of [("Moses", 81.5), ("Dan", 93.66666666666667)]

Comment: at the Student __str__ you could use quotes ```return '"{}", {}'.format(self.__name, self.get_grade_avg())```